# executing java commands from another java file

Tags: java, swing, command-line

```
public String runMsg(String fileName, File Path, int option) 
{
    int x = 0;
    String name = " ", ret = "";

    if (option == 1) {
        x = fileName.indexOf(".c");
        name = fileName.substring(0, x);
        command = name + ".exe < C:\\iptest\\input.txt > C:\\outtest\\" + name + ".txt";
    } else if (option == 2) {
        x = fileName.indexOf(".cpp");
        name = fileName.substring(0, x);
        command = name + ".exe < C:\\iptest\\input.txt > C:\\outtest\\" + name + ".txt";
    } else {
        x = fileName.indexOf(".java");
        name = fileName.substring(0, x);
        command = "java " + name + " < C:\\iptest\\input.txt > C:\\outtest\\" + name + ".txt";
    }

    String output = executeCommand(command, Path);
}

private String executeCommand(String command, File Path)
{
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    Process p;

    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, null, Path);
        p.waitFor();

        BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
        BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        // BufferedReader reader3 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getOutputStream()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader1.readLine()) != null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }
        while ((line = reader2.readLine()) != null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return output.toString();
}
```

I am trying to execute a `.class` file from another java file.  The `.java` file will take input from a txt file located at `C:\iptest\input.txt` and will produce an output file at the following location `C:\outputtest\out.txt` but when I run this application nothing happens and the application goes into some kind of infinite loop.

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Also call flush() on the output. You could also try ProcessBuilder, maybe it's a bit easier. BTW you don't execute *java* files. You need a `java OtherClass` (without the `.class` extension).

Comment: @Marc-Andre the link which you have provided is my own question -_-

Comment: You have to process the output while the sub process is running. You *must not* invoke `p.waitFor();` when there are no threads to handle the input/output of the process.

Comment: @Marc-Andre second code is not a class it is a function and i have used the same function to compile my .java file which is working perfectly and producing the .class file.So i dnt think 2nd function has any problem

Comment: @rick Sorry, I'm lost with all the .class and .java. Holger is right, p.waitFor() is blocking, if you don't handle everything in thread you won't have any output/input.

Comment: use ProcessBuilder is better

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?